# SetCustomValidity based on property in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In a form I wish to not use `onChange`, but rather I have somewhere else where the validity is decided of "data" (it's checked at the server).

I know I can show the pop up by doing something like:

```
class Form extends React.Component {
  onChange(e) {
    let date = new Date(Date.parse(e.target.value));

    if (date > new Date()) {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("Please select a date in the past."); 
    } else {
      e.target.setCustomValidity("");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input
            id="input"
            type="datetime-local"
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

However in my case there is just a property:

```
class Form extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const {invalidMessages} = this.props;

    // how to refer to the input-fields here?
    // invalidMessages, is a map containing "id", "custommessage"

    return <div>
        <form>
          <input
            id="input"
            type="text"
          />
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  }
}
```

What lifecycle method can I use to iterate over all subcomponents, after the components have rendered?

Comment: Isn't that just `componentDidUpdate`? (And I'm not sure why you'd want to iterate over all subcomponents, you'd likely use refs or something.)

Comment: @DaveNewton - I'd iterate to set the custom validity of the components.

Comment: Right, but why? Why iterate over all the subcomponents? There's no need to--we have refs available etc. Iterate over the *errors*, sure.

Comment: @DaveNewton since the subcomponents are dynamically given (by the property `children`) this would be at least confusing as it penetrates several layers of indirection. The documentation on `createRef` is also quite explicit that it should be used sparingly. (Besides it's not relevant to the question?).

Comment: It *should* be used sparingly--but since you're explicitly dealing with DOM fields instead of using a more React-ish approach, this is when you'd want to use them. Of course it's relevant to the question--you explicitly asked how to access DOM elements.

Comment: @DaveNewton if there is a more reactive approach please tell me, I'm all for that: however I can't seem to think of a way to do this.